# Cgo: can't set callback in C-struct from Go

Tags: go, cgo

I have a struct in C lib with some callbacks defined inside it. Problem that Go treat this fields as `*[0]byte` array type and I can't set it to pointer:

```
./test.go:16: cannot use _Cgo_ptr(_Cfpvar_fp_cb_func) (type unsafe.Pointer) as type *[0]byte in assignment
```

Sample of problem code:

```
package main

/*
void cb_func();
typedef struct cb_s {
    void (*cb_f)();
} cb_s;
*/
import "C"

//export cb_func
func cb_func() {}

func main() {
        var x C.struct_cb_s
        // here I want to set callback cb_f to pointer of cb_func().
        x.cb_f = C.cb_func
}
```

One possible solution - write a C setter, something like this:

```
void cb_set(cb_s *s) {
        s->cb_f = &cb_func;
}
```

but it looks ugly: I can't pass cb_func as argument to setter (already tried `cb_set(cb_s *s, void(*func)())`, but got the same error about *[0]byte) and have many similar callbacks, so need to write setter for each pair of callback - callback function.

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 4):

That's exactly how you do it, and yes, it is ugly. Don't forget to add the `extern void cb_func(void);` to your c code.

I ended up with this:

```
/*
 typedef struct {
     void (*cb_f)();
 } cb_s;

 extern void cb_func(void);

 static void cb_set(cb_s *s) {
     s->cb_f = &cb_func;
 }
 */
import "C"

//export cb_func
func cb_func() {}

func main() {
    var x C.cb_s
    // here I want to set callback cb_f to pointer of cb_func().
    C.cb_set(&x)
}
```

Comment: I'm already have almost the same code as noted in question, but place C wrappers in separate *.c file to eliminate double compilation. Thanks anyway.  
Will wait for any other solution, I hope that it exists.

Comment: Were there any other solutions?